# Converting model to different namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

What is the difference between this two? It seems like the latter part can get the job done. Does the latter also execute query? I'm trying to convert a the legacy model into the new namespace without having to re-execute the same query.

The former cant get methods of eloquent, whats the benefit of using this over the latter one

```
$legacyModel = App\Model\User::find(1);
$newModel = (new NewNamespace\Models\Users())->setRawAttributes($legacyModel->getAttributes())
```

vs

```
$legacyModel = App\Model\User::find(1);
$newModel = new NewNamespace\Models\Users($legacyModel->toArray())
```

Comment: There is no issue in using a different name space, it should get autoloader as a normal Laravel class and behave as usual. If you are facing any issue, please specify that.

Comment: Why not just do `NewNamespace\Models\Users::find(1)`?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. You can just use the new namespaced model instead of the old one.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, so the app is 90% using the old namespace ex. legacy model is passed on the event then on the listener I'm trying to convert it to the new namespace model without having to query again. ex.( NewNamespaceUser::find) @apokryfos

Comment: Would doing something like `class User extends NewNamespace\Models\Users` in your legacy model and then removing all code in the legacy model work or are there more incompatibilities?

Answer (score 0):

One is calling the constructor and fires whatever events/actions are related

Constructor:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L232

Setter:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L1776

Notice there is a lot of logic inside the constructor getting the model ready to be used. While the Setter has no extra logic other than filling an array of data.